# Vue 2 with Composition API Reactive

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

For a legacy project we need to use vue 2.
However we want to implement state by using [@vue/composition-api](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) for vue 2

But my only question is, how to use it with options api?

I have a proof of concept with a `.js` file

```js
    import { reactive } from '@vue/composition-api';

    const state = reactive({
        counter : 0
    })

    export default{ state }
```

For setup it is easy:

```html
    <template>
        <h1>hi
            <div>We still in it: {{ counter }}</div>
            <button @click="increment">+</button>
        </h1>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { defineComponent, computed } from '@vue/composition-api'
    
    export default defineComponent({
        name: "TestStateHello",
        setup() {
            const store = require("./useState").default;
    
            return {
                counter: computed(() => store.state.counter),
                increment: () => store.state.counter++,
            };
        },
    })
    </script>
```

But when i want to use regular options api to have access to reactive state of counter i don't seem to know how.

your help will be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import it globally (outside of the returned options object):

```
<template>
    <h1>hi
        <div>We still in it: {{ counter }}</div>
        <button @click="increment">+</button>
    </h1>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, computed } from '@vue/composition-api'
// Alternative (after fixing export): import {store} from './useState';
// You can use this in setup, too - no need to the require inside the setup()
const store = require("./useState").default;

export default defineComponent({
    name: "TestStateHello",
    computed: {
        counter: () => store.state.counter,
    },
    methods: {
        increment: () => store.state.counter++,
    }
})
</script>
```

I suggest you change the export to:

```js
import { reactive } from '@vue/composition-api';

const state = reactive({
    counter : 0
})

export state; // < then import works as above
```

Comment: Thx! This seems like the obvious solution

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with `options api` you can make use of [provide-inject-concept](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html)

How it works.

You can `provide` file of store in main.js like below

```js
import GStore from "./useState"
app.provide('GStore',GStore)
```

Then in component you can `inject` that store

```js
export default {
  inject:["GStore"]
  methods:{

     //Code just to show how to access store counter
     testingState(){
        return this.GStore.state.counter;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good side note! I'm going to try if this still works with SSR